# Error executing a command console cmd

Tags: cmd

I am trying to copy a folder from a local resource to an external resource from a file. Cmd and am using the following command lines

/ / I: is my external drive (DD)

/ / C: is the local disk

I am using a server with Windows Server 2008

```
@ echo off
0f Color
ECHO Start Copying Folders.

if exist I:\CapasClientes (
RD /S /Q I:\CapasClientes ROBOCOPY C:\AZ\MM\CapasClientes I:\CapasClientes *. * / E) else (
ROBOCOPY C:\AZ\MM \CapasClientes I:\CapasClientes *. * / E)
ECHO Folder CapasClientes copied correctly ..

pause

Exit
```

what happens is that I have tested changing the drive (I:) to a local code works perfectly but when I leave the drive (I:) I get an error which says it does not recognize the command "e" which backs up subdirectories of the folder I want to copy.

PDT == I made this same routine on another server and does not leave any error when copying from local drives to the same unit outside.

I appreciate your cooperation ..

Comment: Your code looks botched. There seem to be spurious spaces and missing line breaks. Please fix that. As it is the code can't work.

Comment: the code is correct and work  in other sever , what happen is when i publish the questions was modified by another person.

Comment: Repeating myself, the code as it is posted in your question will. Not. Work. Anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

More simple :

```
@echo off
robocopy "C:\AZ\MM\CapasClientes" "I:\CapasClientes" /ZB /COPYALL /MIR
if errorlevel 8 echo FAIL
pause
exit
```

Parameters used :

- /ZB : Use restartable mode; if access denied use Backup mode.
- /COPYALL : Copy ALL file info.
- /MIR : MIRror a directory tree.

More info at [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)